# Как поставить свой background у floating action button?

Tags: android

Есть floatingaction-кнопка

```
<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.ExtendedFloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"... />
```

Ищу способ сделать свой background. Но проблема в том что в fab свойство background не поддерживается.

можно ли переписать на своё значение background у FAB (вопреки @empty)?
При #ffffff приложение падает

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: зачем вам нужно менять background? если хотите цвет поменять, используйте `app:backgroundTint`, если форму/углы, то `shapeAppearance`

Comment: Как именно вы хотите фон изменить? Если только цвет - есть атрибут `app:backgroundTint`

Comment: @IR42 нужно поставить <animation-list>.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб <animation-list> можно или на background или на foreground. Если на foreground ставить - тогда текст и картинка на кнопке не видны

Answer (score 1):

Никак. Fab не предназначена для такого. Суть fab - минималистичная material design кнопка. Добавление к ней кастомного заднего фона (если вы это имеете в виду) - это как велосипеду третье колесо. Поэтому разработчики и убрали возможность изменения данного атрибута.
Если вам нужен цвет - `app:backgroundTint`, или можете поменять цветовой параметр в темах (не помню какой конкретно, методом проб надо), но тогда у вас изменится цвет и для других элементов темы.

Comment: нужно поставить <animation-list>. А его можно или на background или на foreground. Если на foreground ставить - тогда текст и картинка на кнопке не видны